# Taking bike as luggage from Bratislava to Vienna

Tags: luggage, buses, vienna, bratislava

I want to take my bike as a luggage from Bratislava to Vienna. Do you know if any regular bus line (specifically those departing from bus station at Mlynske Nivy) will accept bike?

If not, can I take it with train?

Comment: It's supposed to be a very nice ride all along the Danube, which a lot of people travel in just to do! Is there a reason why you're not just planning to cycle?

Comment: Because I would be able go only one way in single day. I plan to return from Bratislava by bus/train.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take your bike on a train to Vienna. From [ÖBB website (the national railway system of Austria):](http://www.oebb.at/en/Planning_your_trip/Car_motor-_and_bicycle/Bicycle/Regio-Biking/index.jsp)

> "Regio-Biking" stands for the transport of bicycles on the following
>   trains: Regionalzug (R), RegionalExpress (REX) und S-Bahn.
>
> "Regio-Biking" cannot be booked in advance. Acceptance is subject to
>   the availability of bicycle bays. To allow for maximum flexibility,
>   you will have to load your bicycle yourself when using "Regio-Biking".
>
> **Also for travels with the EURegio Ticket to neighbouring European
>   countries (Czechia, Slovakia, Hungary), the price for bicycle carriage
>   is already included in the ticket price.**
>
> If you would like to search for trains, on which you can take your
>   bicycle with you, in the Online Schedule Information, simply tick the
>   checkbox "Bicycle transport" in the query screen.

[www.wien-vienna.at](http://www.wien-vienna.at/tragfluegelboot-wien-bratislava-wien.php) offers transport by boat between Vienna and Bratislava. One way ticket costs 23 EUR and bike transport costs 4 EUR extra.

Answer (score 2):

By train:

There is a train Bratislava Main St. - Vienna Main St. every hour. Bikes can be taken without extra charge. (Adult fare was 13€).